# Get the elasticsearch results which start with search query to top of the search list

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to get the results which start with `foo bar` to top of the search list. How can i modify my query ?

Expected result list :

`Foo bar,
Foo bar foo,
Foo bar 1,
John doe foo bar,
John foo,
john bar`

```
GET default/media / _search ? pretty
{
    "query":{
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "should": [
                 {
                     "match": {
                     "title": {
                         "query": "foo bar",
                            "boost": 1
                        }
                    }
                 },
                 {
                     "match_phrase": {
                     "title": {
                         "query": "foo bar",
                            "boost": 5
                        }
                    }
                 }
              ]
            }
         },
        "filter": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                     {
                         "term":{
                         "is_active":1
                     }
                    },
                    {
                        "bool": {
                        "should": [
                                {
                                    "bool": {
                                    "must": [
                                           {
                                               "term":{
                                               "media_type_id":1
                                               }
                                           },
                                           {
                                               "term":{
                                               "is_home":1
                                               }
                                           }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "term":{
                                    "media_type_id":3
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                  ]
             }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Scoring doesn't work in filtered queries. Maybe that will work with regular query?

Comment: Can you help me to modify the query?

Comment: Just wipe outer `query` and `filtered` elements with closing brackets, leave only inner query element and try it out. It should look like `{ query: { "bool": { .... `